# how do i get my @host for LN

Tags: lightning-network, hosting

I cannot find where to get the host to complete a lightning channel. I have tried searching in the command prompt but cannot find host info anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little bit underspecified. So not sure if I can really help you. The host is your public IP address so if you are logged on the machine on which the lightning node runs you can try typing `curl -4 https://icanhazip.com/` to the command line.

if you are running `c-lightning` you can do: `lightning-cli getinfo` and it will also depict your public IP address. Not sure if the other implementations have an API call to depict this information.

Comment: LND requires setting the information for generating the certificates for SSL (required) so the user must specify their own information.  Will add a link in a second

Comment: @rene thank you for response i was able to realize my host is my ip address which i was able to obtain. i got the port for LN as well. unfortunately i was still unable to open a channel with a friend. i gave it a try and thank you for the help.

Comment: @pw kad thank you for your reply as well. take care guys.